# Kendo MVVM Grid - Do I Need to Parse JSON Data?

Tags: json, kendo-grid

I am having trouble getting JSON data to display in my grid. The html:

```
<div data-role="grid"  data-bind="source: systems" data-columns='["SystemName", "SystemKey"]' ></div>
```

The mvvm view model:

```
       var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        isVisible: true,
        systems: new kendo.data.DataSource({

            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "system_id"
                }
            },

            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/HomeApi?method=Ref/Systems"
                }
            }
        })
    });
    kendo.bind($("#systems"), viewModel);
```

The structure of the JSON Data:

```
- JSON
     - Data
       - Data
         {}
             SystemName=TIBCO
             SystemKey=TIBCO

             ..... etc
```

Now, if the data were to come back in the following format, it would display fine:

```
[{ "SystemKey": "TIBCO", "SystemName": "TIBCO" }, { "SystemKey": "TIBCO", "SystemName": "TIBCO" }]
```

And yet, as stated, the actual data is in a more complex structure, rather than the simple structure above. So, do I have to parse this in some way, perhaps using schema.parse, to extract the SystemName and SystemKey, since it is down a few levels? Currently no data is displayed in the grid and I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " as an error.

Comment: You could start by showing your code and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: I edited to add more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, I do have to use schema.parse. This is what did it:

```
schema: {
                parse: function (response) {
                    var systems = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.Data.Data.length; i++) {
                        var system = {
                            SystemName: response.Data.Data[i].SystemName,
                            SystemKey: response.Data.Data[i].SystemKey
                        };
                        systems.push(system);
                    }
                    return systems;
                }
            }
```